# Choice of database for a Django-based RSS application?

Tags: python, database, django, rss

I'm planning a web application using Django, and it's based on a big pile of data from RSS feeds. What would be the best database to use to store the content of a lot of posts and metadata, as well as data about how each user relates to each post?

I've heard that the consensus is that ZODB is too slow, but it'd be handy to have a database of persistent objects. The other big options are CouchDB, which I'm not familiar with beyond "schema-less JSON document store", and a normal RDBMS.

Has anyone built something like this before? What'd you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is tuned to work (and perform) nicely with RDBMS, so that's probably the path of least resistance, until you've demonstrated to yourself that an RDBMS won't solve your problem. If you do reach that point, this [page on the wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NonSqlBackends) is probably a good jumping off point for non-relational DBs in Django.